# google apps marketplace workflow

Tags: google-apps

what is the better google appsworkflow products in google apps marketplace workflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Mavenlink and highly recommend them.  Full integration with Google Apps.

Answer (score 0):

KiSSFLOW is the 'intuitive' workflow product built exclusively for Google Apps. It is pre-integrated with Google Apps. 
Give it a try at www.kissflow.com

Comment: Are you in any was affiliated to this application or the company creating it?